# how can I build probability maps with gmapping

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want build probability maps, but I find that gmapping can only generate maps with 3 values (unknown, free and obstacle). How can gmapping work with probablility maps. Thank you.
Further, I change source code, but it doesn't work too.

the code I changed is below:
if(occ < 0)
map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = -1;
else
map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = (int)round(occ*100.0);

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35574/how-can-i-build-probability-maps-with-gmapping/) by [igoliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2527/igoliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not gmapping that is using only three discrete values, but the [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.msg](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html)  message format. Internally, gmapping uses probabilistic cell values, but in the [slam_gmapping.cpp](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/gmapping/html/slam__gmapping_8cpp_source.html) source, starting in line 631, those are converted to above linked message format like so:

```
for(int y=0; y < smap.getMapSizeY(); y++)
{
  /// @todo Sort out the unknown vs. free vs. obstacle thresholding
  GMapping::IntPoint p(x, y);
  double occ=smap.cell(p);
  assert(occ <= 1.0);
  if(occ < 0)
    map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = -1;
  else if(occ > occ_thresh_)
  {
    //map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = (int)round(occ*100.0);
    map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = 100;
  }
  else
    map_.map.data[MAP_IDX(map_.map.info.width, x, y)] = 0;
}
```

Haven't played around with the code, but the occ variable should hold the probability of occupancy.

See also this [question/answer](http://questions.ros.org/question/12914/rviz-display-2d-probabilistic-map/?answer=19068) about visualization in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A_Hari](https://answers.ros.org/users/41462/a_hari/) on 2019-05-10**:
Hi Stefan,
I guess it is an update after a long time!
When I was trying to work on your suggestion and tried assigning the occ value directly to the map data and publish it I find the same -1,0,100 as the values and cant access the probability. Do you have some more input about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would be very surprised if gmapping only outputs three values.
You should have occupancies in the maps. Maybe you are doing something wrong in interpreting the raw data.

Also, the fact that you changed some line of code somewhere and "it doesn't work", doesn't encourage someone to properly help you.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1